# Convert the value of a variable from an integer to a string within another variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert the value of a variable from an integer to a string within another variable. My current code says birthYearString is undefined. Please let me know what would be the best way to go about this.

Current code:

```
const birthYear = 1990;
const birthYearString = toString(birthYear);
```

Comment: `String(birthYear)`

Comment: or `birthYear.toString()`